Wronskian of a system of second-order ordinary differential equations in a special case
\begin{multline*}
 \begin{cases}
  (\kappa+1)(a_{n})^{''}_{\rho\rho}+\frac{\kappa+1}{\rho}(a_{n})^{'}_{\rho}-\frac{\kappa+1}{\rho^{2}}a_{n}+\frac{\kappa n}{\rho}(d_{n})^{'}_{\rho}-\frac{(\kappa+2)n}{\rho^{2}}d_{n}-\frac{n^{2}}{\rho^{2}}a_{n}=0;\\
  -\frac{\kappa n}{\rho}(a_{n})^{'}_{\rho}+(d_{n})^{''}_{\rho\rho}-\frac{1}{\rho^{2}}d_{n}-\frac{(\kappa+2)n}{\rho^{2}}a_{n}-\frac{(\kappa+1)n^{2}}{\rho^{2}}d_{n}+\frac{1}{\rho}(d_{n})^{'}_{\rho}=0;
 \end{cases}
\end{multline*}
Let us now construct the general solution of the subsystem.
For this system of equations, we will look for partial solutions in the form:
$a_{n}=A_{n}\rho^{k_{n}}$, $d_{n}=D_{n}\rho^{k_{n}}$; $A_{n}$, $D_{n}$, $k_{n}=const$.
\begin{multline*}
  \begin{cases}
   (\kappa+1)A_{n}k_{n}(k_{n}-1)\rho^{k_{n}-2}+\frac{\kappa+1}{\rho}A_{n}k_{n}\rho^{k_{n}-1}-\frac{\kappa+1+n^{2}}{\rho^{2}}A_{n}\rho^{k_{n}}+\frac{\kappa n}{\rho}D_{n}k_{n}\rho^{k_{n}-1}-\frac{(\kappa+2)n}{\rho^{2}}D_{n}\rho^{k_{n}}=0;\\
   -\frac{\kappa n}{\rho}A_{n}k_{n}\rho^{k_{n}-1}+D_{n}k_{n}(k_{n}-1)\rho^{k_{n}-2}-\frac{(\kappa+2)n}{\rho^{2}}A_{n}\rho^{k_{n}}-\frac{(\kappa+1)n^{2}+1}{\rho^{2}}D_{n}\rho^{k_{n}}+\frac{1}{\rho}D_{n}k_{n}\rho^{k_{n}-1}=0;
  \end{cases}
 \end{multline*}
\begin{multline*}
  \begin{cases}
   (\kappa+1)A_{n}k_{n}(k_{n}-1)+\frac{\kappa+1}{\rho}A_{n}k_{n}\rho-\frac{\kappa+1+n^{2}}{\rho^{2}}A_{n}\rho^{2}+\frac{\kappa n}{\rho}D_{n}k_{n}\rho-\frac{(\kappa+2)n}{\rho^{2}}D_{n}\rho^{2}=0;\\
   -\frac{\kappa n}{\rho}A_{n}k_{n}\rho+D_{n}k_{n}(k_{n}-1)-\frac{(\kappa+2)n}{\rho^{2}}A_{n}\rho^{2}-\frac{(\kappa+1)n^{2}+1}{\rho^{2}}D_{n}\rho^{2}+\frac{1}{\rho}D_{n}k_{n}\rho=0;
  \end{cases}
 \end{multline*}
\begin{multline*}
  \begin{cases}
   (\kappa+1)A_{n}k_{n}(k_{n}-1)+(\kappa+1)A_{n}k_{n}-(\kappa+1+n^{2})A_{n}+\kappa n D_{n}k_{n}-(\kappa+2)n D_{n}=0;\\
   -\kappa n A_{n}k_{n}+D_{n}k_{n}(k_{n}-1)-(\kappa+2)n A_{n}-((\kappa+1)n^{2}+1)D_{n}+D_{n}k_{n}=0;
  \end{cases}
 \end{multline*}
\begin{multline*}
  \begin{cases}
   ((\kappa+1)k_{n}(k_{n}-1)+(\kappa+1)k_{n}-(\kappa+1+n^{2}))A_{n}+(\kappa n k_{n}-(\kappa+2)n)D_{n}=0;\\
   (-\kappa n k_{n}-(\kappa+2)n)A_{n}+(k_{n}(k_{n}-1)-((\kappa+1)n^{2}+1)+k_{n})D_{n}=0;
  \end{cases}
 \end{multline*}
\begin{multline*}
  \begin{cases}
   ((\kappa+1)k_{n}^{2}-(\kappa+1+n^{2}))A_{n}+(\kappa n k_{n}-(\kappa+2)n)D_{n}=0;\\
   (-\kappa n k_{n}-(\kappa+2)n)A_{n}+(k_{n}^{2}-((\kappa+1)n^{2}+1))D_{n}=0;
  \end{cases}
 \end{multline*}
In order for a homogeneous SLAE to have a nontrivial solution, it is necessary and sufficient that the determinant be equal to zero:
\begin{equation*}
  ((\kappa+1)k_{n}^{2}-(\kappa+1+n^{2}))(k_{n}^{2}-((\kappa+1)n^{2}+1))-(-\kappa n k_{n}-(\kappa+2)n)(\kappa n k_{n}-(\kappa+2)n)=0;
 \end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
  (\kappa+1)k_{n}^{4}-2(\kappa+1)(n^{2}+1)k_{n}^{2}+(\kappa+1)(n^{2}-1)^{2}=0,\kappa\neq-1;
 \end{equation*}
Solving a quadratic equation for $w=k_{n}^{2}$:
\begin{equation*}
  w^{2}-2(n^{2}+1)w+(n^{2}-1)^{2}=0;
 \end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
  w=\frac{2(n^{2}+1)\pm\sqrt{(2(n^{2}+1))^{2}-4(n^{2}-1)^{2}}}{2}=n^{2}+1\pm2n
 \end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
  k_{n_{1,2}}=\pm(1+n), k_{n_{3,4}}=\pm(1-n)
 \end{equation*}
Value Matrix $k_{n}$:
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  -2&0&0&2\\
  -3&-1&1&3\\
  -4&-2&2&4\\
  \dots&\dots&\dots&\dots\\
  -1-n&1-n&-1+n&1+n
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
It shows that we always have four solutions, except for the case $n=1$.
Fundamental solution system: $\rho^{-1-n}$, $\rho^{1-n}$, $\rho^{-1+n}$, $\rho^{1+n}$.
General solution for $n>1$:
\begin{multline*}
  \begin{cases}
  a_{n}=A_{n_{1}}\rho^{-1-n}+A_{n_{2}}\rho^{1-n}+A_{n_{3}}\rho^{-1+n}+A_{n_{4}}\rho^{1+n}\\
  d_{n}=D_{n_{1}}\rho^{-1-n}+D_{n_{2}}\rho^{1-n}+D_{n_{3}}\rho^{-1+n}+D_{n_{4}}\rho^{1+n}
  \end{cases}
 \end{multline*}
Let us separately consider the case for $n=1$:
\begin{multline*}
  \begin{cases}
   (\kappa+1)(a_{1})^{''}_{\rho\rho}+\frac{\kappa+1}{\rho}(a_{1})^{'}_{\rho}-\frac{\kappa+2}{\rho^{2}}a_{1}+\frac{\kappa}{\rho}(d_{1})^{'}_{\rho}-\frac{\kappa+2}{\rho^{2}}d_{1}=0;\\
   -\frac{\kappa n}{\rho}(a_{1})^{'}_{\rho}+(d_{1})^{''}_{\rho\rho}-\frac{\kappa+2}{\rho^{2}}d_{1}-\frac{\kappa+2}{\rho^{2}}a_{1}+\frac{1}{\rho}(d_{1})^{'}_{\rho}=0;
  \end{cases}
 \end{multline*}
The general solution would then look like this:
\begin{multline*}
  \begin{cases}
  a_{n}=A_{n_{1}}\rho^{-2}+A_{n_{2}}+A_{n_{3}}f(\rho)+A_{n_{4}}\rho^{2}\\
  d_{n}=D_{n_{1}}\rho^{-2}+D_{n_{2}}+D_{n_{3}}g(\rho)+D_{n_{4}}\rho^{2}
  \end{cases}
 \end{multline*}
Let us reduce the system to normal Cauchy form by making the following substitution:
\begin{multline*}
  \begin{cases}
   p_{1}=a_{1}\\
   p_{2}=(a_{1})^{'}_{\rho}\\
   p_{3}=d_{1}\\
   p_{4}=(d_{1})^{'}_{\rho}
  \end{cases}
 \end{multline*}
We substitute the replacement into the system above:
\begin{multline*}
  \begin{cases}
   (\kappa+1)(p_{2})^{'}_{\rho}+\frac{\kappa+1}{\rho}p_{2}-\frac{\kappa+2}{\rho^{2}}p_{1}+\frac{\kappa}{\rho}p_{4}-\frac{\kappa+2}{\rho^{2}}p_{3}=0;\\
   -\frac{\kappa n}{\rho}p_{2}+(p_{4})^{'}_{\rho}-\frac{\kappa+2}{\rho^{2}}p_{3}-\frac{\kappa+2}{\rho^{2}}p_{1}+\frac{1}{\rho}p_{4}=0;
  \end{cases}
 \end{multline*}
We leave the terms with the derivative, we transfer the terms without the derivative through the $=$ sign, we divide the first equation of the system by $\kappa+1$:
\begin{multline*}
  \begin{cases}
   (p_{2})^{'}_{\rho}=-\frac{\kappa+1}{(\kappa+1)\rho}p_{2}+\frac{\kappa+2}{(\kappa+1)\rho^{2}}p_{1}-\frac{\kappa}{(\kappa+1)\rho}p_{4}+\frac{\kappa+2}{(\kappa+1)\rho^{2}}p_{3}\\
   (p_{4})^{'}_{\rho}=\frac{n\kappa}{\rho}p_{2}+\frac{\kappa+2}{\rho^{2}}p_{3}+\frac{\kappa+2}{\rho^{2}}p_{1}-\frac{1}{\rho}p_{4}
  \end{cases}
 \end{multline*}
\begin{multline*}
  \begin{cases}
   (p_{1})^{'}_{\rho}=p_{2}\\
   (p_{2})^{'}_{\rho}=\frac{\kappa+2}{(\kappa+1)\rho^{2}}p_{1}-\frac{1}{\rho}p_{2}+\frac{\kappa+2}{(\kappa+1)\rho^{2}}p_{3}-\frac{\kappa}{(\kappa+1)\rho}p_{4}\\
   (p_{3})^{'}_{\rho}=p_{4}\\
   (p_{4})^{'}_{\rho}=\frac{\kappa+2}{\rho^{2}}p_{1}+\frac{\kappa}{\rho}p_{2}+\frac{\kappa+2}{\rho^{2}}p_{3}-\frac{1}{\rho}p_{4}
  \end{cases}
 \end{multline*}
\begin{equation*}
  \frac{dP}{d\rho}=
  \begin{pmatrix}
   (p_{1})^{'}_{\rho}\\
   (p_{2})^{'}_{\rho}\\
   (p_{3})^{'}_{\rho}\\
   (p_{4})^{'}_{\rho}
  \end{pmatrix},
  A(\rho)=
  \begin{pmatrix}
   0&1&0&0\\
   \frac{\kappa+2}{(\kappa+1)\rho^{2}}&-\frac{1}{\rho}&\frac{\kappa+2}{(\kappa+1)\rho^{2}}&-\frac{\kappa}{(\kappa+1)\rho}\\
   0&0&0&1\\
   \frac{\kappa+2}{\rho^{2}}&\frac{\kappa}{\rho}&\frac{\kappa+2}{\rho^{2}}&-\frac{1}{\rho}
  \end{pmatrix},
  P=
  \begin{pmatrix}
   p_{1}\\
   p_{2}\\
   p_{3}\\
   p_{4}
  \end{pmatrix}:
  \frac{dP}{d\rho}=A(\rho)P
 \end{equation*}
We calculate the Wronski determinant (Wronskian):
\begin{equation*}
  det(A(\rho))=(-1)
  \begin{vmatrix}
   \frac{\kappa+2}{(\kappa+1)\rho^{2}}&\frac{\kappa+2}{(\kappa+1)\rho^{2}}&-\frac{\kappa}{(\kappa+1)\rho}\\
   0&0&1\\
   \frac{\kappa+2}{\rho^{2}}&\frac{\kappa+2}{\rho^{2}}&-\frac{1}{\rho}
  \end{vmatrix}=
  \begin{vmatrix}
   \frac{\kappa+2}{(\kappa+1)\rho^{2}}&\frac{\kappa+2}{(\kappa+1)\rho^{2}}\\
   \frac{\kappa+2}{\rho^{2}}&\frac{\kappa+2}{\rho^{2}}
  \end{vmatrix}=0
 \end{equation*}
Please tell me where I went wrong with the calculation of the Wronskian? A fundamental system of solutions, by definition, contains independent solutions, which means the Wronskian should not have turned out to be equal to 0.
